# Check if Folder exists on ArcGGIS Server

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-server

I am writing a python script to deploy a .sd file with the arcpy.UploadServiceDefinition_server method (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/server-toolbox/upload-service-definition.htm). The 5th parameter for this method, in_folder_type, request that I specify that if the destination folder is a new folder or an existing folder. I may not know this at the time that the script is executed, so I would like a way to check if the folder I want to deploy my script to exists already and create it if it doesn't. I tried deploying using the "Existing" flag and a folder name that doesn't exist yet in case that would create the folder for me but the script just put my service in the root of the folder.

Does anyone know a good way in Python or using arcpy to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After consulting colleagues, we found a solution where I don't have to check if the folder exists. The docs for the UploadServiceDefinition_server method mention that besides the Existing and New flags for the  in_folder_type parameter there is the FROM_SERVICE_DEFINITION flag. This option uses the default from the .sd file. I went back in our script to where we generate the .sddraft file with arcpy.mapping.CreateMapSDDraft (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/createmapsddraft.htm) and found that this method has a folder_name parameter that will create the folder if it does not exist. So I set this parameter and and now when I run UploadServiceDefinition_server using in_folder_type='FROM_SERVICE_DEFINITION' it works as expected and I no longer need to check if the folder exists.

Answer (score 4):

How I accomplished this:

1. Write a python script that checks whether a directory exists:

   ```
   import arcpy
   import sys
   import os

   filePath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
   exists = os.path.isdir(filePath)
   arcpy.SetParameter(1,exists)
   ```
2. Add the script to a Geoproccessing Toolbox (make sure to change output parameter to "output" in wizard step 3):
   http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/adding-a-script-tool.htm
3. Run the script as a GP tool from the toolbox so that you get a successful result in the "Result" window. Then publish the service.
   http://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/10.4/publish-services/windows/publishing-a-geoprocessing-service.htm
4. Add the resulting GP Service to a ArcMap model. Use a path that only exists on the server (not locally) to test the result.

You should have a GP service that checks for the existence of a path on the server and returns a "0" or "1" accordingly. You can add this tool to a model or import the toolbox into an arcpy script (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/adding-and-removing-toolboxes.htm)